CloudFlare 400 Error When Calling OpenAI Completions API on CloudRun
Running into a weird error where I get a 400 error from cloud-flare when calling the completions API from GCP Cloud Run. The error doesn't occur locally for identical requests.
The error response:
<html>

<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>

<body>

<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>

<hr><center>cloudflare</center>

</body>

</html>

The request:
POST to https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
{"model":"gpt-4-turbo","messages":[{"role":"system","content":"Using the notes provided, write a summary of the critical information from the notes.\nThe summary should be in dotpoints. Prioritise the dotpoints by importance."},{"role":"user","content":"                Use only the following information to generate the summary:\n                            There are the following notes about the contact:\n            Note Content: \"Test\"\nNote Created At: 2024-09-26T07:08:04.304501Z\nNote is in the context of: Just the contact in the role of Unknown \nNote type: Manual"}]}

Nothing obvious in the headers.
Has anyone run into anything similar. Wondering if its some kind of IP blocking by cloudflare or similar.

So we managed to solve this by switching from using the OkHttp java client, to using the Java 17 core library client.
I suspect there is more to it then that (some configuration on the two clients) but we weren't able to find it at this time.

Facing the same problem at the moment with the direct OpenAI API. It works locally without any issues whatsoever, but I'm receiving a 400 Bad Request on the server from time to time. The same code worked without any problems for a long time. I'm guessing it might be some kind of Cloudflare protection that is blocking requests and marking them as a 400 Bad Request? Moving my service to a different server helped me.
